How do I shift the position of the nth object in an array to the position of the n+1th object
This is the function I made:
func insert_rect(new_index:int, old_index:int):
    test_array.insert(new_index, test_array[old_index])
    test_array.remove_at(old_index+1)
    print("putting " + str(old_index) + "th number in " + str(new_index) + "th index")
    var new_rect_position:float = visualization[new_index].position.x
    if new_index < old_index:
        for i in range(new_index, old_index):
            visualization[i].position.x = visualization[i+1].position.x
    elif new_index > old_index:
        for i in range(0, new_index-old_index+1):
            visualization[new_index-i].position.x = visualization[new_index-i-1].position.x
    visualization[old_index].position.x = new_rect_position

The input of the function is correct and the test array also gives the correct output, but the rectangles end up in the wrong position. I think the problem is the way I'm trying to shift the rectangles positions

What language is that? GDScript? Python? It's probably best to tag the question with the language you are using.

I made some changes to your function code, removing some code I don't understand why is it there and correcting the elif new_index > old_index
def insert_rect(new_index: int, old_index: int):
    print("Putting " + str(old_index) + "th number in " + str(new_index) + "th index")

    new_rect_position = visualization[new_index].position.x
    
    if new_index < old_index:
        for i in range(new_index, old_index):
            visualization[i].position.x = visualization[i+1].position.x
    elif new_index > old_index:
        for i in range(new_index, old_index, -1):
            visualization[i].position.x = visualization[i-1].position.x
    
    visualization[old_index].position.x = new_rect_position

I hope it helped.
